# Is there any sbt plugin can export the dependencies to a json file?

Tags: scala, plugins, dependencies, sbt

I want to export the dependencies of my sbt projects, so I can do some analysis and searching across all projects in one time.

I need a way to export the dependencies(including the dependencies of dependency) to a file in json or some other easy to parse format.

Is there any plugin or tool can do this?

I notice there is a [sbt-dependency-tree plugin](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph), which can only export to some graph format, which is not what I want

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo).

You'll want to work with `managedClasspath` to get the info you want to add to your JSON.

Also remember to enable JSON output with:

```
buildInfoOptions += BuildInfoOption.ToJson
```